# Touchpad and touch screen not found on trekstor notebook

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, touchscreen

18.04  no touchpad and no touch screen found with
trekstor primebook c11 B

works well with Win10

would be very grateful for simple advice :-)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that a merge was made last November (2018) to enable the touchscreen on several computers.  The Primebook 11 was mentioned specifically.  You may need to get a later version of the OS to get the update.  I have also seen descriptions on how to enable the touchpad, but have not tried them.  I'll be reclaiming my Primebook tomorrow night and will begin the investigation myself.